# Sending objects through websocket using ws: Can't deserialize

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angular, websocket

So I tried sending an object through my websocket by translating it to json and then back when it returns. Unfortunately it gives me the below error. The console.log shows me that it is valid JSON, but somehow it gives me an error at JSON.parse in the service document. Can anyone see what I did wrong?

**The error**

```
core.js?223c:1440 ERROR SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at WebSocket._this.ws.onmessage [as __zone_symbol__ON_PROPERTYmessage] (movie-chat.service.ts?6086:22)
    at WebSocket.wrapFn (zone.js?fad3:1166)
```

**console.log result of event.data (valid json)**

```
{"message":"good boy","extra":"extra"}
```

**movie-chat.service.ts**

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import 'rxjs/rx';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

// We need @injectable if we want to use http
@Injectable()

export class MovieChatService {
ws;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

// receive events
createObservableSocket(url:string){
    this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
    return new Observable(observer => {
        this.ws.onmessage = (e) => {
            console.log(e.data);
            var object = JSON.parse(e.data);
            observer.next(object);
        }
        this.ws.onerror = (event) => observer.error(event);
        this.ws.onclose = (event) => observer.complete();
    }
    );
}
// send events
sendMessage(message) { 
    message = JSON.stringify(message);
    console.log(message);
    this.ws.send(message); 
}

}
```

**Back-end handling of messages**

```
var wss = new Websocket.Server({port:3185});
var CLIENTS = [];

wss.on('connection',
    function(websocket) {

        CLIENTS.push(websocket);
        websocket.send('connected to socket');


        websocket.on('message', function (message) {
            console.log('Server received:', message);
            sendAll(message)
        });

        websocket.on('close', function(client) {
            CLIENTS.splice(CLIENTS.indexOf(client), 1);
        });

        websocket.on('error', function(client) {
            CLIENTS.splice(CLIENTS.indexOf(client), 1);
        });
});
```

**movie-chat.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
import { MovieChatService} from "./movie-chat.service";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-movie-chat',
    templateUrl: './movie-chat.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./movie-chat.component.css']
})

export class MovieChatComponent implements OnInit{

    fullName;
    messageFromServer;
    title = 'Websocket Demo';
    url;
    ws;
    messages = [];

    constructor(private movieChatService: MovieChatService){
    }

    ngOnInit(){
        this.fullName = localStorage.getItem('fullName');
        this.url = 'ws://localhost:3185';
        this.movieChatService.createObservableSocket(this.url)
            .subscribe(data => {
                    this.messageFromServer = data;
                },
                err => console.log(err),
                () => console.log('The observable stream, is complete'));
    }

    sendMessageToServer(){
        console.log('Client sending message to websocket server');
        this.movieChatService.sendMessage({
            message: 'good boy',
            extra: 'extra'
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are trying to parse a Json Object,

```
{"message":"good boy","extra":"extra"}
```

JSON.parse expect string parameter and you are passing an Json Object for that the exception is rised. 
We try to surround the Parse with try and catch

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import 'rxjs/rx';
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";

// We need @injectable if we want to use http
@Injectable()

export class MovieChatService {
ws;

constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

// receive events
createObservableSocket(url:string){
    this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
    return new Observable(observer => {
        this.ws.onmessage = (e) => {
            console.log(e.data);
            try {
                var object = JSON.parse(e.data);
                observer.next(object);
            } catch (e) {
                 console.log("Cannot parse data : " + e);
            }
        }
        this.ws.onerror = (event) => observer.error(event);
        this.ws.onclose = (event) => observer.complete();
    }
    );
}
// send events
sendMessage(message) { 
    message = JSON.stringify(message);
    console.log(message);
    this.ws.send(message); 
}

}
```

Comment: Is there a way around this?

Comment: The error appear when you try to send message to the server?

Comment: I receive the above in my service when I get it back from the server. The error occurs when I try to transform this JSON back into a Javascript object.

Comment: I edit my post, try to update the on message method and restart the server and let me know if the issue still persists.

Comment: The server now returns this: "{\"message\":\"good boy\",\"extra\":\"extra\"}". It double serialized it and JSON.parse() still leads to an error unfortunately.

Comment: I did notice that I can also send the data in an array without any issues, but it would be nice to do it in an object.

Comment: Can you just and the try and catch statement like I edit the post to be sure about the content of the data that rise the exception.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and your patience. It now returns an actual JS object. I thought try/catch was only for catching errors? I didn't know it could also solve them. Anyway, thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I didn't actually solve it the way I wanted it, but I found out that it is possible to send arrays through a websocket. I did this and on the receiving end I transferred it into an object in the service file. It does the job for now. If anyone knows a better solution, let me know :)

```
createObservableSocket(url:string){
        this.ws = new WebSocket(url);
        return new Observable(observer => {
            this.ws.onmessage = (e) => {
                var obj = e.data.split(',');
                console.log(obj);
                obj = {
                    name: obj[0],
                    msg: obj[1]
                };
                console.log(obj);
                observer.next(obj);
            }
            this.ws.onerror = (event) => observer.error(event);
            this.ws.onclose = (event) => observer.complete();
        }
        );
    }
```